# I generate my data set using GAN, but the image resolution is not good

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Reshape, Dropout, Dense 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
import os 
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

GENERATE_RES = 3 # Generation resolution factor 
# (1=32, 2=64, 3=96, 4=128, etc.)
GENERATE_SQUARE = 32 * GENERATE_RES # rows/cols (should be square)
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3

# Preview image 
PREVIEW_ROWS = 4
PREVIEW_COLS = 7
PREVIEW_MARGIN = 16

# Size vector to generate images from
SEED_SIZE = 100

# Configuration
DATA_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/cars/images'
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
BUFFER_SIZE = 60000

print(f"Will generate {GENERATE_SQUARE}px square images.")

def hms_string(sec_elapsed):
    h = int(sec_elapsed / (60 * 60))
    m = int((sec_elapsed % (60 * 60)) / 60)
    s = sec_elapsed % 60
    return "{}:{:>02}:{:>05.2f}".format(h, m, s)

training_binary_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH,
        f'training_data_{GENERATE_SQUARE}_{GENERATE_SQUARE}.npy')

print(f"Looking for file: {training_binary_path}")

if not os.path.isfile(training_binary_path):
  start = time.time()
  print("Loading training images...")

  training_data = []
  faces_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH)
  for filename in tqdm(os.listdir(faces_path)):
      path = os.path.join(faces_path,filename)
      image = Image.open(path).resize((GENERATE_SQUARE,
            GENERATE_SQUARE),Image.ANTIALIAS)
      training_data.append(np.asarray(image))
  training_data = np.reshape(training_data,(-1,GENERATE_SQUARE,
            GENERATE_SQUARE,IMAGE_CHANNELS))
  training_data = training_data.astype(np.float32)
  training_data = training_data / 127.5 - 1.


  print("Saving training image binary...")
  np.save(training_binary_path,training_data)
  elapsed = time.time()-start
  print (f'Image preprocess time: {hms_string(elapsed)}')
else:
  print("Loading previous training pickle...")
  training_data = np.load(training_binary_path)

#shuffle the data
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data) \
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

def build_generator(seed_size, channels):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(4*4*256,activation="relu",input_dim=seed_size))
    model.add(Reshape((4,4,256)))

    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
   
    # Output resolution, additional upsampling
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    if GENERATE_RES>1:
      model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(GENERATE_RES,GENERATE_RES)))
      model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,padding="same"))
      model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
      model.add(Activation("relu"))

    # Final CNN layer
    model.add(Conv2D(channels,kernel_size=3,padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    return model


def build_discriminator(image_shape):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=image_shape, 
                     padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    return model

def save_images(cnt,noise):
  image_array = np.full(( 
      PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_ROWS * (GENERATE_SQUARE+PREVIEW_MARGIN)), 
      PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_COLS * (GENERATE_SQUARE+PREVIEW_MARGIN)), 3), 
      255, dtype=np.uint8)
  
  generated_images = generator.predict(noise)

  generated_images = 0.5 * generated_images + 0.5

  image_count = 0
  for row in range(PREVIEW_ROWS):
      for col in range(PREVIEW_COLS):
        r = row * (GENERATE_SQUARE+16) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
        c = col * (GENERATE_SQUARE+16) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
        image_array[r:r+GENERATE_SQUARE,c:c+GENERATE_SQUARE] \
            = generated_images[image_count] * 255
        image_count += 1

          
  output_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH,'output')
  if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.makedirs(output_path)
  
  filename = os.path.join(output_path,f"train-{cnt}.png")
  im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
  im.save(filename)

generator = build_generator(SEED_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)

noise = tf.random.normal([1, SEED_SIZE])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0])

image_shape = (GENERATE_SQUARE,GENERATE_SQUARE,IMAGE_CHANNELS)

discriminator = build_discriminator(image_shape)
decision = discriminator(generated_image)
print (decision)

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1.5e-4,0.5)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1.5e-4,0.5)

@tf.function
def train_step(images):
  seed = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, SEED_SIZE])

  with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    generated_images = generator(seed, training=True)

    real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
    fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
    

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(\
        gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(\
        disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(
        gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(
        gradients_of_discriminator, 
        discriminator.trainable_variables))
  return gen_loss,disc_loss

def train(dataset, epochs):
  fixed_seed = np.random.normal(0, 1, (PREVIEW_ROWS * PREVIEW_COLS, 
                                       SEED_SIZE))
  start = time.time()

  for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch_start = time.time()

    gen_loss_list = []
    disc_loss_list = []

    for image_batch in dataset:
      t = train_step(image_batch)
      gen_loss_list.append(t[0])
      disc_loss_list.append(t[1])

    g_loss = sum(gen_loss_list) / len(gen_loss_list)
    d_loss = sum(disc_loss_list) / len(disc_loss_list)

    epoch_elapsed = time.time()-epoch_start
    print (f'Epoch {epoch+1}, gen loss={g_loss},disc loss={d_loss},'\
           ' {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}')
    save_images(epoch,fixed_seed)

  elapsed = time.time()-start
  print (f'Training time: {hms_string(elapsed)}')

train(train_dataset, EPOCHS)
```

output:

Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Will generate 96px square images.
Looking for file: /content/drive/MyDrive/cars/images/training_data_96_96.npy
Loading previous training pickle...
tf.Tensor([[0.500162]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
Epoch 1, gen loss=1.2521650791168213,disc loss=1.914326548576355, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 186ms/step
Epoch 2, gen loss=1.7096827030181885,disc loss=0.5423159599304199, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 3, gen loss=2.272305965423584,disc loss=0.8929743766784668, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 4, gen loss=2.2072598934173584,disc loss=0.25587552785873413, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 5, gen loss=2.3019070625305176,disc loss=0.21757033467292786, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step
Epoch 6, gen loss=2.575505018234253,disc loss=0.17825308442115784, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 7, gen loss=3.332831382751465,disc loss=0.14639586210250854, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 8, gen loss=3.433645248413086,disc loss=0.10990916937589645, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 9, gen loss=3.3049514293670654,disc loss=0.11572304368019104, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 10, gen loss=3.609067678451538,disc loss=0.09259825199842453, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 11, gen loss=3.7380425930023193,disc loss=0.06529977172613144, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 12, gen loss=3.8801209926605225,disc loss=0.14237746596336365, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 13, gen loss=3.130918502807617,disc loss=0.10186785459518433, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 14, gen loss=3.3608131408691406,disc loss=0.14246127009391785, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 15, gen loss=3.547894239425659,disc loss=0.06966713815927505, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 16, gen loss=3.815532922744751,disc loss=0.08421273529529572, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 17, gen loss=3.722708225250244,disc loss=0.1032436192035675, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
Epoch 18, gen loss=3.739579200744629,disc loss=0.046980421990156174, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 19, gen loss=3.739589214324951,disc loss=0.08560846745967865, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 20, gen loss=4.255866050720215,disc loss=0.05066610872745514, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 21, gen loss=3.957040548324585,disc loss=0.07933451235294342, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 22, gen loss=3.880115509033203,disc loss=0.04236868768930435, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 23, gen loss=4.06533145904541,disc loss=0.19700711965560913, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 24, gen loss=3.3864612579345703,disc loss=0.07393720746040344, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
Epoch 25, gen loss=3.3804116249084473,disc loss=0.05958547815680504, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 26, gen loss=3.821190357208252,disc loss=0.04148954153060913, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 27, gen loss=4.464746952056885,disc loss=0.05721660703420639, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
Epoch 28, gen loss=3.6131443977355957,disc loss=0.05866093561053276, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
Epoch 29, gen loss=4.744598865509033,disc loss=0.02504117041826248, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 30, gen loss=5.070501327514648,disc loss=0.03655111417174339, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 31, gen loss=5.028214454650879,disc loss=0.05283133313059807, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 32, gen loss=4.512475967407227,disc loss=0.029515832662582397, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
Epoch 33, gen loss=4.234488487243652,disc loss=0.04423428326845169, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
Epoch 34, gen loss=4.756722450256348,disc loss=0.027692552655935287, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 35, gen loss=4.627975940704346,disc loss=0.034884288907051086, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
Epoch 36, gen loss=4.613211631774902,disc loss=0.02385132387280464, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step
Epoch 37, gen loss=5.285978317260742,disc loss=0.029336072504520416, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step
Epoch 38, gen loss=4.975574493408203,disc loss=0.04948919638991356, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step
Epoch 39, gen loss=5.21699333190918,disc loss=0.024706657975912094, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step
Epoch 40, gen loss=4.772751808166504,disc loss=0.017935097217559814, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step
Epoch 41, gen loss=4.907123565673828,disc loss=0.01947692222893238, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
Epoch 42, gen loss=5.128135681152344,disc loss=0.0248250812292099, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step
Epoch 43, gen loss=5.214532852172852,disc loss=0.018172364681959152, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step
Epoch 44, gen loss=5.159983158111572,disc loss=0.012960834428668022, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step
Epoch 45, gen loss=4.758917808532715,disc loss=0.0272075068205595, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 46, gen loss=5.529351711273193,disc loss=0.014828093349933624, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 47, gen loss=5.728432655334473,disc loss=0.12049077451229095, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 48, gen loss=4.203306674957275,disc loss=0.03110041655600071, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
Epoch 49, gen loss=3.988110065460205,disc loss=0.04727930203080177, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 50, gen loss=4.492999076843262,disc loss=0.033211976289749146, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 51, gen loss=5.042882919311523,disc loss=0.016409948468208313, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 52, gen loss=5.537625789642334,disc loss=0.026737529784440994, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
Epoch 53, gen loss=5.211821556091309,disc loss=0.010845048353075981, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 54, gen loss=5.701164722442627,disc loss=0.04262271150946617, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 55, gen loss=5.542649269104004,disc loss=0.022705482318997383, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 56, gen loss=5.372197151184082,disc loss=0.015590135008096695, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
Epoch 57, gen loss=5.6270246505737305,disc loss=0.022842954844236374, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 58, gen loss=5.408458232879639,disc loss=0.009651245549321175, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 59, gen loss=5.241275310516357,disc loss=0.015216059982776642, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
Epoch 60, gen loss=5.165868282318115,disc loss=0.029404155910015106, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 61, gen loss=5.145402908325195,disc loss=0.06437502801418304, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 62, gen loss=4.79179573059082,disc loss=0.017924988642334938, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step
Epoch 63, gen loss=4.649152755737305,disc loss=0.03150978684425354, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
Epoch 64, gen loss=5.010418891906738,disc loss=0.017228417098522186, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 65, gen loss=4.756021499633789,disc loss=0.027317486703395844, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step
Epoch 66, gen loss=5.622550964355469,disc loss=0.01270538754761219, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 67, gen loss=6.158242225646973,disc loss=0.017070528119802475, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 68, gen loss=5.928429126739502,disc loss=0.01662832498550415, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 69, gen loss=5.386126518249512,disc loss=0.013434197753667831, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
Epoch 70, gen loss=6.026540756225586,disc loss=0.02687542513012886, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 71, gen loss=5.261167526245117,disc loss=0.023555422201752663, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 72, gen loss=5.738616943359375,disc loss=0.014481189660727978, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 73, gen loss=5.241582870483398,disc loss=0.019968684762716293, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 74, gen loss=5.925738334655762,disc loss=0.00579763064160943, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 75, gen loss=5.720101356506348,disc loss=0.011479364708065987, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 76, gen loss=6.193869590759277,disc loss=0.006102893501520157, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 77, gen loss=5.537936210632324,disc loss=0.010631267912685871, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 78, gen loss=6.044013977050781,disc loss=0.01976114511489868, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
Epoch 79, gen loss=5.948068618774414,disc loss=0.00767383212223649, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step
Epoch 80, gen loss=6.257611274719238,disc loss=0.004831803496927023, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step
Epoch 81, gen loss=5.845160961151123,disc loss=0.013850312680006027, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step
Epoch 82, gen loss=6.311680793762207,disc loss=0.008116095326840878, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step
Epoch 83, gen loss=5.450529098510742,disc loss=0.020070217549800873, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
Epoch 84, gen loss=5.884340286254883,disc loss=0.00944106187671423, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step
Epoch 85, gen loss=5.81611442565918,disc loss=0.012152504175901413, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step
Epoch 86, gen loss=5.939234733581543,disc loss=0.015416755340993404, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step
Epoch 87, gen loss=5.972536087036133,disc loss=0.017035959288477898, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step
Epoch 88, gen loss=5.9316205978393555,disc loss=0.011325504630804062, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 89, gen loss=6.045965671539307,disc loss=0.012280451133847237, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
Epoch 90, gen loss=5.950098037719727,disc loss=0.008400402031838894, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
Epoch 91, gen loss=6.041635513305664,disc loss=0.010960103943943977, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 92, gen loss=6.382598876953125,disc loss=0.013652551919221878, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 93, gen loss=5.5880279541015625,disc loss=0.008998909033834934, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 94, gen loss=5.931588172912598,disc loss=0.030779847875237465, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 95, gen loss=5.870139122009277,disc loss=0.022104108706116676, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Epoch 96, gen loss=5.459892272949219,disc loss=0.014665926806628704, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Epoch 97, gen loss=5.578482627868652,disc loss=0.012628478929400444, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step
Epoch 98, gen loss=5.386386394500732,disc loss=0.014529233798384666, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
Epoch 99, gen loss=5.727524280548096,disc loss=0.01658312976360321, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
Epoch 100, gen loss=5.722194671630859,disc loss=0.010024849325418472, {hms_string(epoch_elapsed)}
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step
Training time: 0:00:39.99
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ahkt.png)

Comment: can't you adjust the resolution by just modifying the `GENERATE_RES` parameter ?